# Uncaught InvalidStateError in KineticJS: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that
>   is not, or is no longer, usable.

What means this error? I'am trying to do this:

```
if(node.main_photo === 'no_photo.png')
{ 
    nodeIconImg.src = '<?= URL::to(''); ?>/img/' + node.main_photo;
}
```

the string are correct, the file exists, but why I get this error?

Comment: What line produces this error? Can you provide some more code or a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that the string doesn't contain "invisible" chars, line-breaks or white-spaces.

You can debug this by doing:

```
if(node.main_photo === 'no_photo.png') { 

    console.log(escape('<?= URL::to(''); ?>/img/' + node.main_photo));

    nodeIconImg.src = '<?= URL::to(''); ?>/img/' + node.main_photo;
}
```